# how can I overlay a rectangle ontop of MediaPicker?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms, how can I overlay a rectangle ontop of MediaPicker? Based on this Rectangle size & position, I should be able to crop auto manually

currently, rectangle doesnt show up ontop of live camera

I have a basic Constructor, that is calling overlayrectangle() method

```
   public MyCLass()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             OverlayRectangle;
    
         }
```

//function that creates a basic rectange

```
 void OverlayRectangle()
 {
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
     rect.Width = 200;
     rect.Height = 100;
 }
```

//user click on button to capture a photo code

```
              //Pick a image
              var options = new MediaPickerOptions
             {
                 Title = "Please select a Image"
             };
             var result = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync(options);

             if (result != null)
             {
                 //crop image
                 var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                 using (var newImage = await CrossImageEdit.Current.CreateImageAsync(GetImageStreamAsBytes(stream)))
                 {
                     var croped = await Task.Run(() =>
                             newImage.Crop(10, 20, 250, 100)
                                  .Rotate(180)
                                  .Resize(100, 0)
                                  .ToPng()
                 );

                     //display
                     ImagePage1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(croped));
                 }
             }
```

Comment: do you want to display an overlay on top of the camera preview?  The old media picker allowed that, but I don't think the new one does.  You probably need to write a custom renderer.

Comment: "live camera" not preview

Comment: potato, potahto - the answer is the same